# Web3JS contract call returning a different value than direct contract call with remix

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I have a contract deployed onchain:

```
    function getNonces(bytes32 _hashWalletSig, uint256[] calldata _dataTypes)
        public
        view
        virtual
        returns (uint8[] memory, bytes32[] memory)
    {
       ...
    }
```

If I point the remix editor to this contract and call the getNonce() function directly with the parameters:

`0xa58d6abf78c9492df62daf0e251c6af49d5101eaadf2c4786e277a8da97f9f73` and `[0]`

I get my expected result.

However, I have a frontend application using Web3Js that attempts to call the getNonce function but I'm getting a completely different value (i.e. 0x00000000) which indicates that nothing is found:

```
export const getBlockchainStatus = async (walletSignature: string): Promise<boolean> => {
  const MainContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    Ky0xMainAbi as AbiItem[],
    CONTRACT_ADDRESS,
  );

  const hashwalletSig = ethers.utils.keccak256(walletSignature);
  console.log('hashwalletSig:', hashwalletSig);
  const response = await MainContract.methods.getNonces(hashwalletSig, ['0']).call();
  console.log('response', response[1][0]);
  return response[1][0] !== '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';
};
```

The hashWalletSig matches the original value that I passed into the remix editor.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in Web3JS?

Comment: It might be caused by different values stored in the contract (when you're accessing it from one source or the other), or by different network params ... 1) Can you share the `getNonces()` content, incl. its dependencies (e.g. if it's accessing a contract property or performing a nested function call)? ... 2) Are the Remix and JS codes accessing the contract on the same network? Example: In Remix, you're deploying the contract to a local emulated network and the JS code accesses the contract on the mainnet.

Comment: @PetrHejda thanks for the comment. the getNonce function uses msg.sender and I assumed that it would be using the default metamask account to make the call but that's not the case